# Отступы белого цвета

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать белые отступы на странице, те что помечены красным в body в css?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS:

```
.belyy_otstup{
  background-color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
line-height: 28px;

}
.seraya_seredina{
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  border-color: #d7d7d7;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="belyy_otstup">menu_punkt1|menu_punkt2|menu_punkt3</div>
<div class="seraya_seredina">Тут основной сайт</div>
<div class="belyy_otstup">menu_punkt1|menu_punkt2|menu_punkt3</div>
<body>
```

не понял вопроса, ес честно.

Answer (score 0):

Верхний отступ: так как написано выше.

Нижний отступ: [как прижать футер к низу страницы css](http://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&newwindow=1&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+css&oq=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%84%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80+%D0%BA+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83+%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B+css&gs_l=hp.3...1661.13858.0.14074.23.15.1.7.7.0.69.462.15.15.0...0.0...1c.1.rGp0rCo5Nu8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bGE&fp=2a886e48bec1cc17&bpcl=40096503&biw=1600&bih=809).